# Dynamic event binding not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to bind a tr click event to my datatable.

This is my code now:

```
$(myDataTable).find("tbody tr").on("click", function (e) {
//do the magic
});
```

It works for the first page. On second page i got no click event.

.live and .delegate also not work.

Anyone with a solution and can say why this is not working? 
I would prefer not to use the dataTables render callbacks.

Comment: can you please provide your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with dynamic element use the following code

```
$(myDataTable).on("click","tbody tr", function (e) {
//do the magic
});
```

[**Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/on/**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

To bind to dynamic elements you must do this

```
$(myDataTable).on("click","tbody tr", function (e) {
//do the magic
});
```

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: [, selector ] [, data ], parameter is option so OP code is ok

Comment: @PranayRana If the <tr> elements are dynamic OP's code wont work